# Setting up WebGL shaders on Mac, Three.js, & vite-plugin-glsl

Tags: macos, three.js, shader, webgl, vite

I am working on learning shaders through Three.js but I am having a bit trouble trying to get the setup to work. I am using vites plugin glsl for my shader which I have set up. At first I tried following along some more advance videos, but the glsl/frag/vert files didn't seem to work so I found a video that brought it down to the basicss. Thankfully I can get the shader to visualize and change color, but it looks like my vertex shader does not want to work. Originally I placed them in separate GLSL files, but that was giving me more problems that way, so I opted towards  embedding them inside of my JS files. Here is my current basic project.

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";


const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight)
camera.position.set(-10, 10, -1)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
const canvas = document.body;
canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);


// Lights
const ambientLights = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
scene.add(ambientLights)

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight('#ffffff', 1);
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
directionalLight.receiveShadow = true;
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 0.01;
directionalLight.shadow.normalBias = 1.05;
directionalLight.position.set(200, 400, 10.25);

scene.add(directionalLight);

const shaderMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: `
        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
        uniform float uFrequency;
        uniform float uAmplitude;

        attribute vec3 position;

        void main() {
            vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

            // anything I place in here doesn't update
            modelPosition.y += sin(modelPosition.x * uFrequency) * uAmplitude;
            vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
        `,
    fragmentShader: `
        precision mediump float;

        void  main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
        }
        `,
    wireframe: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    uniforms: {
        uFrequency: { value: 10.0 },
        uAmplitude: { value: 0.1 }
    }
})

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10),
    shaderMaterial
)

plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
plane.castShadow = true;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(plane);


const animate = () => {
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

The fragment shader works because I see the change in color, however my vertex shader is where the issue lies. It doesn't disappear, but nothing changes and it also doesn't throw any errors to debug. Whenever I try updating my vertex shader, nothing happens. So it's semi working, but can't really do anything pass setting it up like so. I understand that WebGL was deprecated for MACs, but I always notice several videos online with mac users still using it, so I figure it has to work, there must be some things I'm just missing

Comment: The expression you assign to `gl_Position` does not use `modelPosition` or `viewPosition`, so changing those variables won't affect the output position. Exactly what do you try to change in your vertex shader and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Berthur I referenced [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF2nJxoIA6c&t=1284s&ab_channel=AlvaroDevLabs) (around the 13 minute mark) where they used the modelPosition variable to make simple updates such as offsetting the objects positioning. I want to do more ofcourse, but at the core basics it seems not to be doing anything at all

Comment: @Berthur Wow...took me coming back here a second time, rereading your statement and taking a look at my code. I must have skipped a part of the video and didn't realize I never updated my `gl_Position`.  Working as expected now! Thank you. Now I wonder if I can get things going with exporting them into there own glsl files. Is there any different setup that you are aware of that I should be cognizant of? I've seen some videos were things like the `projectionMatrix` aren't explicitly defined in vert files, or am I mistaken by that?

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Not sure what you mean by that. In WebGL, it's common to write the shaders in a JS string, or sometimes in an HTML element or separate JS file. Your `projectionMatrix` is not defined in your shader, it's a uniform and this is also common.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to examples that reference the `projectionMatrix` without having to declare it like `uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;`? This is because they use Three.js' [ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shadermaterial#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial), where much of the GLSL boilerplate is already included for you. See [ShaderChunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk.js).

Comment: @Berthur Ahhh, I've never heard or have been aware of this repo. A Godsend. Now it makes more sense!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your vertex shader is that you're assigning values to `modelPosition`, but then you're not using them! When you assign the final output to `gl_Position`, you're not using any of the calculations you performed previously:

```glsl
void main() {
    // You create and modify modelPosition...
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    modelPosition.y += sin(modelPosition.x * uFrequency) * uAmplitude;
    vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;

    // ...but then you don't use it on your final output!
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Instead of doing all the matrix multiplications again from scratch, just make sure you use the position you've modified.

```glsl
void main() {
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    modelPosition.y += sin(modelPosition.x * uFrequency) * uAmplitude;
    vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;

    // Make sure you use viewPosition in your final output
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
}
```